# Sort Array by String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Right now, I have a list of streams, and I want to push streams with the string "online" to the front of the array, but I want to do this very quickly. I know I can just duplicate the array value by value and push the online values to the front, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

This is just some sample code but it is similar to what I have going. How can I just rearrange my array to push online toward the front? I'm open to JavaScript or jQuery answers.

```
var streams = new Array('online', 'offline', 'online', 'offline', 'online', 'offline', 'offline', 'online');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
streams.sort()
```

Would give you `["offline", "offline", "offline", "offline", "online", "online", "online", "online"]`

since f comes before n in off and online

You can use `.reverse()` to reverse the order of elements.

```
streams.sort().reverse()
```

Should be what you are looking for, you don't need to reassign the array (i.e. doing `streams = streams.sort().reverse()`) as it does the operations internally within your array.

Answer (score 3):

use the built-in array functions:

```
streams.sort().reverse();
```

That was easy...

**MDN docs:**

- [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 2):

```
streams.sort();
```

Otherwise you probably just want to loop through the array.

Comment: if I use sort(), it does it alphabetically from my understanding and will push offline to the front.

Comment: oh, heh. In fact, just duplicating the array might be faster than sorting it.